# What is the safest way of modifying element's html wth jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Long time ago I used

```
$("#someid").html( $("#someid").html() + "Something added" );
```

Before knowing that .append() exist. Above code sometimes behaving weird too.

But now I want to modify the HTML content instead using `replace()` command. Now the only way to modify the code that I can think of is

```
$("#someid").html( $("#someid").html().replace("XXX","YYY"));
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Javascript templates might be a good alternative to complex dom manipulations.

Comment: The [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. That might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to put the text you want to change in it's own

```
<span id="something">text here</span>
```

Then, you can manipulate the HTML only on a single object and not affect all the other objects.

```
$("#something").html("something new");
```

or depending upon what you're replacing with:

```
$("#something").text("new text");
```

This is much, much safer and more efficient than using `.html()` on a large block of HTML containing many objects which will disconnect any event handlers you already have in place on that HTML and cause the browser to have to reparse, reformat and redisplay a large amount of HTML.

Comment: Indeed this is more efficient. But using `.text()` instead of `.html()` would be even safer.